# Ember-data: How do I set an incoming null value to an empty string value?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember-Data (v1.13.13) to manage objects coming from the server.

The value of an incoming attribute is null.  The attribute type is a string with default value being an empty string.  The null is not defaulting to the empty string as expected.  So it looks like Ember-Data establishes a nullable string data type by default (thinking about it in general terms, not a JavaScript thing, of course).

In any case, I would like to know how to convert the incoming null to the default empty string value as the model is "instantiated".  That or indicate to Ember-Data to consider the property in terms of a string type rather than a nullable string type.

The model (simplified):

```
App.Note = DS.Model.extend({
    mystring: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: '' })
});
```

The incoming object:

```
{
    "notes": [{
        "mystring": null
    }]
}
```

The resulting value in memory:

```
<App.Note:ember1133:1775>
mystring: null
```

Comment: Default values are typically for new records, not old ones.   Deal with the null, imo -- that is 'the truth'.

Comment: You're probably right.  I was using default values to set the initial type of the incoming items.  Of course as soon as you edit a bound number it converts to a string anyway.  Need to respect the JavaScript variable behavior.  Been caught up on the server-side for too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null and empty string are different, so it is not surprising that Ember Data's `string` transform does not do that conversion. However, you can write your own which does:

```
// transforms/string-null-to-empty.js
export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize(serialized) { return serialized || ''; },
  serialize(deserialized) { return deserialized; }
});
```

then

```
mystring: DS.attr('string-null-to-empty')
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the `normalize` method in your RESTSerializer will also do the trick. Something like this should work

```
DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   normalize: function(modelClass, hash, prop) {
     // Do whatever checking you need to to make sure
     // modelClass (or hash.type) is the type you're looking for
     hash.mystring = hash.mystring || '';
     return this._super(modelClass, hash, prop);
   }
 });
```

Of course, if you don't always know which keys you'll need to normalize from null to an empty string then you could just iterate over all of them (however this will be slower).

```
DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   normalize: function(modelClass, hash, prop) {
     Object.keys(hash).forEach(function(key){
       hash[key] = hash[key] || '';
     });
     return this._super(modelClass, hash, prop);
   }
 });
```

Comment: You should call `super` and also return the result.

Comment: @torazaburo Oh yea, of course, thanks. Silly oversight by me there.