# How do I standardize my use of moment.js in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, momentjs

I have an Ember application that receives several data models from the server each of which may contain dates.

I am using moment.js to manage and manipulate dates in the browser.  Conversion and management of this has gotten messy.

I would like to simplify, and have all dates uniformly used as moment.js objects. But will be JS Date objects in all communication with the server.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution that I found, thanks in part to a previous related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015484/ember-data-how-do-i-set-an-incoming-null-value-to-an-empty-string-value)

First, create a serialization/deserialization transform that converts the data type:

```
App.MomentTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
   deserialize: function (serialized) { 
      return serialized
         ? moment(serialized).locale((navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage).slice(0, 2)) 
         : null; 
   },
   serialize: function (deserialized) {
      return deserialized 
         ? deserialized.toDate() 
         : null; 
   }
});
```

Second, register the transform:

```
App.register("transform:moment", App.MomentTransform);
```

Third, use the transform for any dates in the model definition:

```
App.MyModel= DS.Model.extend({
    someData: DS.attr('number'),
    dateTime: DS.attr('moment')  <--
});
```

In this way, all dates will enter the application as moment objects and be converted back to JS Date objects before being sent to the server.

Comment: Where does `App.register('transform:moment', App.MomentTransform)` go? I keep getting `Unable to find transform`